# Having trouble with if statement

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Aside from that how old are, because I'm 15.");
String age = input.nextLine();
```

> next line has a problem but don't know why on netbeans. I think it has to do something with the tweenty.

```
if(age > 20){
System.out.println("Were not really the same age.");
}
```

Comment: How can a string be higher than 20? Use `input.nextInt()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a String object to an integer.
First convert the String to an integer, then compare the integers.
To do this, use `Integer.parseInt(age)`. This will return an integer that is equal
to the number written in the string.

```
String age = input.nextLine();
int ageInteger = Integer.parseInt(age);
if (ageInteger > 20) {
    System.out.println("...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 2 ways

1. you can convert string to integer :

```
  System.out.println("Aside from that how old are, because I'm 15.");
  String age = input.nextLine();
  int ageInInt = Integer.parseInt(age);
  if(ageInInt > 20){
      System.out.println("Were not really the same age.");
  }
```

Or 2. you can read an in from input :

```
System.out.println("Aside from that how old are, because I'm 15.");
int ageInInt = input.nextInt();
if(ageInInt > 20){
    System.out.println("Were not really the same age.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
String age = input.nextLine();
```

to:

```
int age = input.nextInt();
```